# Django: "No comment found matching the query" 404 Error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I'm making a simple blog app with comments on a 'posts detail view' page, but I'm getting a 404 error saying "No comment found matching the query" whenever I try submitting my comment. Everything else in the app works except for the comments. I'm new to django and am making this site to learn, would appreciate any help!

**Views.py**

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
  model = Post
  fields = ['content']

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
  model = Comment
  fields = ['content']
  template_name = 'blog/comment.html'

  def form_valid(self, form):
    post = self.get_object()
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment {self.content} by {self.author.username}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('comment', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    UserPostListView,
    CommentCreateView
) 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('post/comment/<int:pk>/', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
]
```

**comments.html** This is the form. It's supposed to redirect to a different form to comment then back to post detail view

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Comment</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div> 

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Comment does not have pk until it is created.

Comment: You comment form is not on the post detail page, right?

Comment: Why do have the line `post = self.get_object()` in your `form_valid()` method? Since the model is `Comment` and you're creating a new comment, `self.get_object()` will raise a 404.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by the comment not having a pk until created?

Comment: and the comment form is not on the same page as post detail

Comment: I removed the post=self.get_object() and got "IntegrityError at /post/comment/31/
NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_comment.post_id:". Is that an issue with my URLs?

Comment: 1) `'post/comment/<int:pk>/', CommentCreateView` + `model = Comment` - Django treats this PK as a Comment pk, not Post. 2) `post = self.get_object()` this assignment has no effect on neither form nor comment instances - `post` here is a standalone variable never used after assignment.